# Can someone explain the grammar of this sentence?

Tags: grammar, usage

In this sentence:

> 日本中に、世界中にこれからずっと大切にしていきたい仲間ができたことに感謝！

This is my translation (not confident of it's accuracy):

"I am grateful that I was able to make companions that I want to cherish forever from now on, in Japan and the world."

The context is someone returning to Japan from overseas exchange.

---

I have several questions regarding the gramar of the sentence:

1. Is the に particle in 日本中に、世界中に used to indicate the person's friends in Japan and in the world?
2. Does これからずっと mean "from now on I will do continuously" and, in this case does it mean "forever"?
3. With this part: 大切にしていきたい,

   why the していきたい part conjugated as しる + くる. How would it be different if it is just したい without くる to make 大切にしたい?
4. Is this whole clause これからずっと大切にしていきたい describing the person's 仲間? And can be translated as "From now on I want to cherish my 仲間 forever."
5. I am most confused with how できたこと is used. I interpreted it as "was able to do" in the translation but I don't understand how it connects with the rest of the sentence in this case.

I would appreciate a more literal translation of the sentence that can help me understand the grammar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your translation looks good. To address your specific questions:

1. Yes, that's correct. Note that ○○中に indicates "throughout", not just "in", so it's more like "friends all around Japan and the world".
2. Yes, ずっと generally indicates "forever" and this is no exception.
3. I'm not sure where you got しる + くる from. The verbs that are combined to form していきたい are する and 行く. Specifically, it's the common ～ていく construction meaning "to do something from now on/going forward". Since this nuance is already stated in これから, the meaning wouldn't really change much if you used just したい instead, but していきたい feels more natural.
4. Yes, that whole phrase is a relative clause modifying 仲間, and your interpretation seems on the mark.
5. One of the meanings of できる (arguably the core meaning, though certainly not the most common) is "to be made/completed", as in for instance スーパーの隣に新しいビルができた "A new building has been built next to the supermarket". This sense of できる is perhaps more familiar in the compound verb できあがる, which *only* has this meaning of "to be completed". One very common use of this sense of できる is in forming relationships, so you can say 新しい友達ができる "to make a new friend", 彼女ができた "I got a girlfriend", etc. 仲間 of course works in the same way, so 仲間ができた here is "made new friends/companions".

Comment: ずっと can also mean "up until now".

Comment: To be fair, that can often be treated as essentially the same meaning, just in combination with the past tense. (As in "it has been that way forever, until X happened.") But yes, ずっと always meaning "forever" is a slight simplification. Perhaps more accurate would be to say it refers to something happening for "the whole time" - which depending on context can mean it will go on indefinitely into the future, has been going on indefinitely into the past, or has been going on continuously since some defined point in time. (It also has some other distinct uses, but those aren't very relevant here.)